# Toshiba A505 - S6965 Running Windows XP Pro

Tags: windows-xp, toshiba-laptop

I have a copy of Windows XP Pro that I want to put on my Toshiba Satellite A505 - S6965. I tried to put it on yesterday, but nothing works, not even the Ethernet port. What should I do to make it work correctly? Also, the resolution was acting funny...

Answer (score 0):

You would need drivers for the hardware that comes with the laptop. You could probably [find these drivers](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=2346348&rpn=PSAP3U&modelFilter=A505-S6965&selCategory=3&selFamily=1073768663) on the Toshiba website.

Good luck with, and hope this helps some.